# Show the clusters, not individual pins

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a js code and in there I try to create a clusters in order to be like the following image: [image]

However, I want to provide only the clusters, without reaching at the point where the individual pins are provided. My code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function initialize()
{
    <?= $geoData ?>
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {     
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(50, 0), 1);
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());         
        // Create our "tiny" marker icon
        var icon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);       
        icon.image = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png";              
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < <?= $total_records ?>; i++) {
          var latlng = new GLatLng(geo_data.records[i].lat, geo_data.records[i].lng);
          var marker = new GMarker(latlng, {icon: icon});
          markers.push(marker);
        }
    var zoom = 14;
            var size = 60;
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,  {maxZoom: zoom, gridSize: size} );
   }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 initialize();
</script>
```

What should I change into my code in order to get rid of the individual clusters?

Comment: You're using Google Maps API v2, which is deprecated and will stop working in May 2013.  You should rewrite it to API v3.

Comment: @duncan can you please help me to change edition?

Comment: Your code doesn't look too complicated.  Read up Google's migration guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3  and if you have specific problems, ask them as new questions on StackOverflow :-)